# geopandas to_crs epsg:3347

Tags: geopandas, pyproj, epsg

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.to_crs('epsg:3035').plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

changing to epsg:3347 gives wrong projection.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.to_crs('epsg:3347').plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

it should be centered over North America, see [here](https://epsg.io/3347)

package version are

```
pyproj.__version__ = 3.3.1
gpd.__version__    = 0.12.2
```

Comment: Why is it wrong?  What's wrong about it?

Comment: I edited the post and added image from the projection

Comment: Why do you think that's wrong?  Isn't that Alaska at the southeast and Florida at the northeast?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to keep only North America

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world[world['continent'].str.contains('North America')].to_crs('epsg:3347').plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]